# how to use nRows and nCols in chart.add_series in xlsxwriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

My data is updating on daily basis and for plotting graph I've to find the last column(yesterday data) as I've used pivot and to find last column I've used df.shape[1] and same value assigned to nCols and for another sheet I'm using last row but its not against pivot. when I use nCols and nRows values in chart.add_series it doesn't plot graph and even don't give me error.